# how to convert a float value to an integer number in php

Tags: php

i have a function for forex site that subtract two numbers like the following example

```
140.50 - 140.00
1.1010 - 1.1050
1.5215 - 1.5058
```

what i get is the following

> 0.5
>
> -0.004
>
> 0.0157

what i want to get is the following

> 50
>
> -40
>
> 157

i have tried the following

```
$number = 1.5058 - 1.5215;
list($real, $decimal) = explode('.', $number);
echo $result = $number*pow(10,strlen($decimal));
```

but i got

> 5
>
> -4
>
> 157

because the zero in the right is no sense for it

Comment: Are the numbers always in a equation, or are stored in separate variables?

Comment: yes its always equation the same way and its in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after ?

```
function remdec($num) { return intval(str_replace(".", "", strval($num))); }

$number = remdec(1.5058) - remdec(1.5215);
echo $number;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://viper-7.com/xJc9es)**

Comment: Your welcome, there would be other ways to come to the same result, glad you liked thou.